# mysql SELECT all orders with values from last revision

Tags: mysql

this is my DB model from my application.
With php I am creating all orders list like this

```
SELECT id, date from orders
```

and after that Im using another SELECT to select data only from last revision for this order

```
SELECT name, material, producer, color from revisions WHERE id_order = id ORDER BY date LIMIT 1
```

then I get all orders with information only from last revision for order.

Is it possible to create SELECT to do this all in only one query? I am new to JOINing tables.. model was easy to create but I dont know how to select all this information in one query. I need something like this:

```
SELECT id, date (order table), name (revision table), 
name of material (material table), 
name of producer (producer table), name of color (color table).
```

and this will create list of all orders with some information only from last revision.

THANKS a lot for all your replies

[image: DB schema]

Comment: [Refer This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and try yourself. No spoon feeding :)

Comment: Ever heard of a **JOIN**, google it!

Comment: Please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 or http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp. Those are good starting points to understand the various answers you will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method summarizes the revisions, choosing the date of the last one for a given order.  It then joins this information back in:

```
SELECT r.name, r.material, r.producer, r.color
from revisions r join
     (select r.id_order, max(date) as maxdate
      from revisions r
      group by r.id_order
     ) rmax
     on rmax.id_order = r.id_order and
        rmax.maxdate = r.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a join for the two table.

```
SELECT o.id, o.date, r.name, r.material, r.producer, r.color 
FROM orders o 
JOIN revisions r ON r.id_order = o.id 
ORDER BY date 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but this will return data from all revision of orders, and I need to display only data from last added revision